How to back up Ubuntu OS partition(s) and restore when needed
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04.
GParted:

I want to a) make a separate partition for data files; and b) make an image of the partition(s) that would be needed to restore my PC to today's configuration should I wish to do so in the future.  What's the best way for an Ubuntu novice to accomplish these tasks?
I'll use GParted to make new partition(s).  I've read that one can make system images with Clonezilla or gnome disks. I know how to back up my data files.

Don't bother with the OS Only backup personal data and make a script where you add in the commands you use to alter settings, (all desktop alterations can be done with a gsettings command),  The quickest way to back up personal data is using a tool that uses rsync. "deja dup" is a backup tool. don't use software that close a disk (or dd it),

Clonezilla is a good place to start.  Why don't you install it and look at the official [documentation}(https://clonezilla.org/) and give it at try?

I prefer rsync, but any of the gui apps that use rsync underneath should work. Best to still know some of the settings for rsync. I backup /home which I keep inside / (root), but have all data in data partition(s) which I separately backup. I also export list of installed apps as part of my rsync script. The few files in /etc that I edit like grub, I copy into /home so backed up.

"any advice" will lead to a lot of opinions. So here's mine: Merely take notes on the customizations you make and the software you install. Don't bother re-partitioning. A page or two of notes is much simpler, and you already know how to use your notes on the day you want to revert. You already know how to backup your data. Be aware that settings and customizations come and go as the Desktop Environments evolve. A setting on 24.04 might not still be there in 26.04; notes are flexible when that happens.

Thank you to all who responded. I've started taking notes when I change my installation.  It's very helpful.It turned out that my live usb from Macrium Reflect can backup and restore Ubuntu images. I tried it and it worked. Cheers,  Joe
